# Primefaces ajax issue with ui:include

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have added ui:include and now some ajax events within the included page are not firing.

Some ajax calls are working, but specifically the update on pe:inputNumber is not:

```
<pe:inputNumber value="#{trans.toBeAllocatedAmount}"
<p:ajax listener="#{bankBean.updateAllocatedTotal()}"
update="tblReceipts" />
</pe:inputNumber>
```

is not firing any ajax calls.

If I put the page in directly instead of an include it works.

I have PF5 and PE2

Any ideas or suggestions as to what the issue could be?

I have rolled it back and it appears to be PF5 related.

Comment: If you can't seem to identify the root cause in PF5, create and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @BalusC - aside from doing that though, how would you go about finding the root cuase of this, given that I have rolled back to PF4 and it works. I have just had a bug report filed in PF rejected as being 'not related to Primefaces' ?

Comment: As said, by creating and posting a MCVE.